# jquery validation in mvc3 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Can someone help me to do validation in mvc3 html editable grid?  The sum of the values on the column should not exceed one hundred.  Can I validate using jQuery or do server-side validation?

Answer (score 0):

**This is Server Side Validation**

Class:

```
public class Party
{
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Start date is required")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Duration is required")]    
public int DurationInHours { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "No. of joinees is required")]
[Range(2, 10, ErrorMessage = "No. of joinees should be minimum 2 and not more than 10")]
public int NoOfJoinees { get; set; }    

public bool Drinks { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class PartyController: Controller
{
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
}
```

View:

```
@model CustomValidation.MVC.Models.Party

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary()


Start date (MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss AM/PM) *: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartDate, new { size = 25 })
Duration (Hours) *: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DurationInHours, new[]{
                        new SelectListItem(){ Text = "1", Value = "1"},
                        new SelectListItem(){ Text = "2", Value = "2"},
                        new SelectListItem(){ Text = "3", Value = "3"},
                        new SelectListItem(){ Text = "4", Value = "4"},
                        new SelectListItem(){ Text = "5", Value = "5"}
                        }, "Select the duration", new { style = "width:180px" })


    No. of joinees *: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NoOfJoinees, new { size = 5 })

    Drinks? @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Drinks)

    <input type="submit" value="Host the party!" />
}
```

**And Client Side Validation:**

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName"/>
<input type="button" onclick="Validation()" value="Enter" />
```

Javascript:

```
function Validation() {
var data= {
UserName: $('#UserName').val()
};

if (data.UserName.trim() == "" || data.UserName== undefined) {
$("#ShowWarning").html('<img src="/Image/warning.jpg" title="Please Enter UserName!">').show();
}
```

Also you can check below example too

http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/d17c1dc9-e00b-4c13-94e7-87dacdca027f/?Validation%20in%20ASP%20NET%20MVC3

i hope helps you

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, you should always use client side and server side validation. If you mark the models with validation attributes both the server-side and client-side validation should work just fine.

Please check this  link for detailed validation in MVC3 - http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html

And also check this below Scott-Gu blog which helps for validation.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx